# How to disable links in HTML until a values is set in the database

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink

I want to disable four links until a particular link is clicked by the user and he completes the registration.

Here is how it would look.

Link 1
Link 2
Link 3
Link 4
Link 5

I want to disable the links except Link 1, so that the user clicks on it and completes the registration. After completing the registration the status field in a table is changed to 'C'. Only after which the four other links must be enabled. Can you suggest a way to achieve this using JS or PHP.

This is how i tried.

LINK 1 
IF (mysqli_query()== Condition specified ) //To query if the particular value is set in the database
{
Link 2
Link 3
Link 4
Link 5
}

But by this way all the four links would appear only if the registration is complete by clicking on link 1. How do I show the four links as disabled until the registration is complete.

Comment: Look into PHP's `isset()` and for DB use a `WHERE` clause and `UPDATE`, which seems to be part of what you are using, even though it wasn't tagged as such. This is too broad a question and not knowing which SQL API you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using php. Have a simple if statement to check if link 1 is compete and if so display the other link else do nothing.

If you wanted to do it with JavaScript you would want to make an Ajax call at the end of the form process, which you will need to do anyways, but you could just return a value to that Ajax call which could either switch the links "on" or trigger the php. The php will need a refresh so depending on the flow of the site it may make sense to return something that will flip the links "on". You could even look into returning HTML markup and would be appended to the Navbar.

Thinking about this more you could even flip the links active when the user clicks submit using JavaScript. The downside is that the links are already displayed so link 1 could be bypassed pretty easily. Just depends on your target users and how secure it needs to be.

Edit after OP added code:
`LINK 1
IF (mysqli_query()== Condition specified ) //To query if the particular value is set in the database { 
    Link2d Link3d Link4d Link5d } 
else { 
    Link2a Link3a Link4 aLink5a
}`

Where d is disabled and a is active.

Comment: I have tried it the same way with PHP. But I want the user to see the other links a disabled until the link 1 registration is completed.

Comment: So if link1 == complete display active link else display disabled link. Will probably need a refresh to make the change though

Answer (score 0):

This is a start for your problem. It uses jQuery to hold the links until the form is submitted. Once submit is clicked, it will fill in the links. You should also add validation to the form and whatnot. 
[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwolybug/dk4Lummm/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#submit").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("ul#navbar").html('<li><a href="page1.html">Link 1</a></li><li><a href="page2.html">Link 2</a></li><li><a href="page3.html">Link 3</a></li><li><a href="page4.html">Link 4</a></li><li><a href="page5.html">Link 5</a></li>');
        $("td").text('C');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
    <li>Link 5</li>
</ul>
<form action="#" method="POST">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<table border="1px solid black">
<tr><th>Form</th></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```